# What is the base function name for Menu and Home buttonPressed? Xamarin Form C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

[image: OnBackButtonPressed()]

[image: Base]

I am trying to find other ButtonPressed base functions (Home &  Menu), but i could not find it.
Is anyone know how to control or execute events when the Menu and Home button is pressed in Xamarin Form C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my query, there is no directly used function.
I realized this function by broadcasting.

Here is my solution(All the code is added in Android.MainActivity):

Register the broadcast in **OnCreate** of **Android.MainActivity**.

```
RegisterReceiver(new broadcastReceiver(), new IntentFilter(
          Intent.ActionCloseSystemDialogs));
```

Realize the internal operation of broadcasting.

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class broadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    string SYSTEM_REASON = "reason";
    string SYSTEM_HOME_KEY = "homekey";
    string SYSTEM_HOME_KEY_LONG = "recentapps";
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        string action = intent.Action;
        if (action.Equals(Intent.ActionCloseSystemDialogs))
        {
            string reason = intent.GetStringExtra(SYSTEM_REASON);
            if (reason.Equals(SYSTEM_HOME_KEY))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Home click");
            }
            else if (reason.Equals(SYSTEM_HOME_KEY_LONG))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Menu click");
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Man you are the best. simple, short, yet clean and super effective. i have received what i want. appreciated it!